# Batch file to search for a file, then delete that and the parent folder

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

Basically I need to search the folders within `C:\Windows\ccmcache` and search for *adobe cc.msi* and then delete the entire contents of that directory

This is what I already have

```
@echo off 
set dir="c:\windows\ccmcache\" 
FOR /D %dir% %%X IN (adobe cc.msi) DO DEL /S /Q "%%X" 
pause 
exit
```

Comment: Got this far and stuck as im clueless @echo off
set dir="c:\windows\ccmcache\"
FOR /D %dir% %%X IN (adobe cc.msi) DO DEL /S /Q "%%X"
pause
exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test it with a dummy dataset before trying it out on the actual folder you wish to delete (I've tested but you can confirm at your end as well)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set adobe=adobe cc.msi
echo %adobe%
pause
FOR /R M:\windows\ccmcache %%G IN ("*") DO (
set trgt=%%~nG%%~xG
IF /I "!trgt!"=="%adobe%" RMDIR /S /Q %%~pG
)

pause
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried but no success, basically when we carry out deployments via SCCM and in the ccmcache folder they leave various folders labelled a, b, 1, 2, 3 etc and within the folder the various MSI's we created so the adobe folder is 16GB and need to clear the contents.  I understand the syntax used and it looks right so i cant see where it would have gone wrong

Comment: Is the Script being run with Administrator priviliges ? Did it work with another folder that you created for testing the script ?

Comment: I tried it on my c: and d: drive both with admin privileges on local admin and domain admin and moved it to different shares etc

Comment: okay. The only difference is that the file you've mentioned is "adobe cc.msi". My script searches for "adobecc.msi". Notice the missing whitespace. Account for that in the script please

Comment: Hi Dhiwakar, I noticed this earlier and changed it.  I created another script which looks in all the folders within ccmcache and detects anything called adobe cc.msi but i cant seem to get it to store the variable and then delete the contents of the directory that the msi is located in.  strange one

Comment: Please remove /Q during delete to wait for a prompt. If the prompt appears then there's some issue with deleting it, if the prompt does not appear then its failing to identify the file itself and could be an issue with the script. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Actually if i create a file in that folder called adobecc.msi (no space) i get prompted to del the file and the process goes like this so its nearly there.  i put quotes around adobe cc.msi to account for the whitespace but this didnt work.

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

u:\>c:

C:\>deladobecccache.bat
adobe cc.msi
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\>
C:\>deladobecccache.bat
adobecc.msi
Q, Are you sure (Y/N)? y
The system cannot find the file specified.
\Windows\ccmcache\g\, Are you sure (Y/N)? y

C:\>^A

Comment: Actually it works if i put the /s and /q lowercase and remove the whitespace, almost there thanks

Comment: All i need to do is somehow have it so i can use the space.  i tried setting a variable at the start called SET%adobe% ="adobe cc.msi% and replacing the adobe cc.msi to %adobe% further down the line with no success either

Comment: Please see my updated script. It must work with whitespace characters in the name. I've verified on my setup. Finally if you think this answer helped you solve the issue you were facing please mark it as selected & upvote Thanks :)

Comment: For the benefit of others - This is NOT the correct way to delete content from the SCCM Cache. The Content is indexed in a file and simply deleting the files/folders will cause issues.
You should be using a script to interact with SCCM to perform this task; there are a number of scripts easily searchable online, the best i have found will delete old cache items (not accessed over a certain period) and can also set the cache limit to a size dynamically, based on the local disk size.
Also, SCCM should automatically manage the cache content based on free space so it doesnt fill the local disk.